# this.state is undefined inside child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, typescript

In my code, I have the `render()` function. In this method this.state is available. If `this.LoadingIcon` just contains text, all is good:

```
public render() {
    return <div>

            <h1>Search company</h1>

            <this.LoadingIcon />

            <label value={this.state.query} />

            <div className='form-group'>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' value={this.state.query} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
            </div>

            <button onClick={() => { this.searchVat() }}>Search</button>
        </div>;
}
```

However, if I suddenly want to use the state and make the LoadingIcon conditional:

```
LoadingIcon(props: any) {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return <h1>LOADING</h1>;
    } else {
        return <h1>NOT LOADING</h1>;
    }

}
```

You get the:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

Why is this? And how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- `this.state` is undefined because `LoadingIcon` is a [stateless component](https://javascriptplayground.com/functional-stateless-components-react/)
- in React, the parent's state is not directly available in the child component

To access the parent's state in the child, you need to pass the state as prop:

```
<this.LoadingIcon loading={this.state.loading} />
```

Then in your child component, you can use the props to retrieve the parent's state:

```
LoadingIcon(props: any) {
    if (props.loading) {
        return <h1>LOADING</h1>;
    } else {
        return <h1>NOT LOADING</h1>;
    }
}
```